Read boolean value of application property in class level annotation
Using Spring Boot 2.7/3.x, is there a way to get the value of a boolean parameter of a class level annotation from a property file?
My original concern was the possibility of an opt-in/opt-out strategy with @RepositoryRestResource in SDR. I know about RepositoryDetectionStrategies, but I was looking for an even more finer-grained mechanism:
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = <true|false>)

where I could get the value of exported from my application-*.properties files, each profile defining it's own set of exports.
Reading a string value this way is easy when it's a string:
@Annotation(parameter = "${my.property}")

But for a boolean, you get a conversion error incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean.
In a nutshell, I'm open to suggestions for both the specific case of a property-based opt-in for RepositoryRestResource and the more general issue of assigning a non-string property value into a class level annotation.
